# Reduce a number down to a static set of numbers

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas, counting, google-sheets-query, cumulative-sum

Okay, so I have a Google Sheet that I need to reduce a number down to a specific set of 4 numbers.  Then count how many times those numbers occur.

For example:

The numbers it breaks down to:  `1, 2, 3, 4`

Disregard their individual values other than for the purpose of being broken down.

Now take the number `17`.

```
Count+Add 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3 = 7 r1
```

Take number `12`

```
Count+Add 1, 2, 3, 4, 1 =  r1
```

The remainder is rounded DOWN

So, basically, it breaks down Cell A1 into a count of how many sequences it takes to reach the total of the number in A1, rounddown.

Comment: You may want to restate your question.  I assume you are looking to do this in Google, which cannot use macro functions.  Is the given set [1, 2, 3, 4] constant, or do we need to be prepared for that set to change?  Are you more interested in the result or the process?  There are a few ways to solve it, and without a little more context to your question, I would like to make sure your are getting the answer you are really looking for.

Comment: @Nick Google sheets can use macros: [tag:google-sheets-macros]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(COUNTA(IFERROR(QUERY(MMULT(TRANSPOSE((
 ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&A2*COUNTA(SPLIT(B2, ","))))<=TRANSPOSE(
 ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&A2*COUNTA(SPLIT(B2, ","))))))*TRANSPOSE(
 SPLIT(QUERY(B2&IF(ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&A2))<>"", ",")
 ,,9^9), ","))), SIGN(TRANSPOSE(
 SPLIT(QUERY(B2&IF(ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&A2))<>"", ",")
 ,,9^9), ",")))), "where Col1 <="&A2, 0))))
```

[image]

Comment: That's a heck of a code!  

As a note, the sequence will always be static per subject.  In this case, the sequence is 1,2,3,4.  Sometimes it will be 2,4,6,8.

This formula will take the defined sequence in Column B?

Comment: @MichaelDeArmon yes it will

Answer (score 1):

Seems odd but...

Your sequence adds to 10, so your number tens place and above times 4 is your first element.  Then if the ones digit is between 6 and 9 you add 3, 3 to 5 add 2, or 1 to 2 add 1.  There is probably a more elegant formula that this...

`=(INT(A1/10)*4)+IF(MOD(A1,10)>0,1,0)+IF(MOD(A1,10)>3,1,0)+IF(MOD(A1,10)>5,1,0)`

Comment: But what if I were to change the sequence values?